# SQL Query Speed. Compare Query 1 vs Query 2

Tags: sql

I have the following two sample queries. Why is the first one so much slower than the second one? Where CustomerTable is a list of all Customers ie. Customer Name, Customer Number, Customer Address, Phone, email, etc.

The RevenueTable contains all the invoice transactions and the customerNo as the foreign key.

QUERY 1

```
 SELECT c.CustomerName, c.CustomerNumber, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount
 FROM CustomerTable c LEFT JOIN
      RevenueTable r
      ON c.CustomerNumber = r.CustomerNumber
 GROUP BY c.CustomerName, c.CustomerNumber
```

QUERY 2

```
SELECT c.CustomerNumber,CustomerName, Total 
FROM CustomerTable c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT CUstomerNumber, SUM(Amount) as Total
      FROM revenueTable r
      GROUP BY CustomerNumber
     ) r
     ON c.CustomerNumber = r.CustomerNumber 
WHERE Total IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan)

Comment: Many reasons, sizes of tables, indexes, keys, etc.  As above check the execution plan

Comment: One possibility is that in the second query, the set of data to `JOIN` to is [probably] much smaller.  But as suggested, your first stop should be to check the execution plan.

Comment: Are you sure its the same data? Different fields are used in *revenueTable* between queries: *CustomerNo* vs. *CustomerNumber*?

Comment: The second one is basically an inner join with the null check on `Total`. Likely results in a different query plan that is much more optimized. I would personally write this a third way, borrowing from the first query but an inner JOIN and a `SUM() OVER` windowing function.

Comment: @DBro Yes, That is correct the inner query has fewer rows than the outer query. But  the overall number of rows in the revenueTable is much larger. Would that be the reason if so can you explain why that would cause it to be faster?

Comment: @Cory thanks for your input, can you give me an example of how to write it using the SUM() Over feature. I would like to see if the performance is better.

Comment: If this is SQL Server run  `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` before you run the queries to see more information in the Messages window.  This info helps, but capturing the *actual* execution plan is key to understand issues like this.

Comment: IMHO, let the optimizer decide what to do and use QUERY 1. With QUERY 2, you are forcing the execution of the revenueTable sub-query first. I am not saying that it is bad as it really depends on your tables, indexes, etc, but you should trust the optimizer. Why are you in this dilemma? Maybe you are trying to optimize a query when you need an index, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the "...overall number of rows in revenueTable is much larger" presumably than the customer table. Assuming that the revenueTable is some sort of transaction or sales table, this would make sense (a customer would - hopefully - make more than one transaction).

So, as *a_horse_with_no_name suggested*, check the execution plan.

Let's put some numbers to the tables sizes. Assuming Customers has, say, 1,000 rows and revenueTable has 1,000,000 rows, then query 1 will join all of the customers to the revenueTable, i.e. expand the 1,000 customers to 1,000,000 records aligned with each revenueTable record. Then add them all up.

The second query will add up all of the Amounts first (i.e. collapse the 1,000,000 records to 1,000 records - because there are 1,000 customers). Then the join is 1,000 to 1,000 records (as opposed to the 1,000 to 1,000,000 record join in query 1.

Hopefully, you can see that query 1's expansion of the 1,000 customers to the 1,000,000 revenue records and then SUMming the new larger 1,000,000 records is more work than first collapsing the 1,000,000 revenue records to just 1,000 and then joining those 1,000 summed revenue records to the 1,000 customer records.

Again, check the execution plan to determine exactly what is happening, this is just my best guess based upon the information provided.

BTW. I am ignoring the OUTER JOIN, but the basic principle is still the same if you allow for the possibility that some customers have no revenue records. This just means that query 2 will collapse the 1,000,000 revenue records into a number of records even lower than 1,000 - depending upon how many customers have no revenue records (e.g. 100 customers have no revenue records, the inner query in Query 2 will generate 900 records).

Comment: @Al_1999 if this has helped you, could you please accept the answer (click on the grey check mark next to the answer) and upvote it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The second query will have less data in the LEFT JOIN because of the GROUP BY.